# is a number field by definition a subfield of $ \mathbb C $?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, field-theory, algebraic-number-theory

I have seen that some authors are defining the number field as a **subfield of $ \mathbb C$** which is a finite extension of the rational numbers $ \mathbb Q $, while some others without referring to complex numbers $ \mathbb C$ .
I think we don't need $ K$ to be a subfield of $ \mathbb C$ in the definition.
So, my question is the follwing:

> Is it neceserily to define $K$ as a subfield of $ \mathbb C$ or not ?
> And if no why ? Is it true that if we omit this in the definition, that then $K$ will turn out to be a subfield of $ \mathbb C$?

I came up with this question, when I saw that in order to define infinite primes in a number field then these are determined by the embeddings $ K \to \mathbb C $

Any idea would be really appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: A number field is a *finite* extension of $\Bbb{Q}$. As such, it is always isomorphic as a subfield of $\bar{\Bbb{Q}}$, which embeds in $\Bbb{C}$: there are exactly $[K:\Bbb{Q}]$ copies of $K$ in $\Bbb{C}$, given by the embeddings.

Comment: For example, the number field $K=\mathbb Q(\sqrt{-1})$ can be seen as a subfield of $\mathbb C$ via the two embeddings $K \hookrightarrow \mathbb C,\ \sqrt{-1} \mapsto \pm\sqrt{-1}$.

Comment: If you don´t defined K as a subfield of C you find out later to be in effect a subfield of C because all the root of the involved polynomials defining the generators of K are in C (which is algebraically closed, a fundamental result).

Comment: A number field is an algebraic extension of the rationals. To compare field extensions etc it is useful to fix a algebraic closure. In arithmetic case the complex numbers are obvious candidate. Also in arithmetic geometry this helps because Lefshetz principle offers some intuition.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Usually there will be more than one way to consider $K$ as a subfield of $\mathbb{C}$ - or more precisely, to embed $K$ in $\mathbb{C}$.

For example, take $K:=\mathbb{Q}[X]/(X^3-2)$, which is to say the extension field of $\mathbb{Q}$ of degree $3$ containig a root of the polynomial $X^3-2$ (which root we choose is irrelevant for now).
Then we can embed $K$ into $\mathbb{C}$ by mapping that fixed abstract root of the polynomial to the complex number $\sqrt[3]{2}$, which is also a real number, or the complex number $\sqrt[3]{2}\cdot \exp(\frac{2\pi i}{3})$, which is a non-real complex number.

So we have embedded $K$ into $\mathbb{C}$ in two disctinct ways. This distinction would have been "lost", had we considered $K$ as a subfield of the complex numbers from the start.

Comment: It wouldn't have been lost. You could still consider the field embeddings of $K$ in $\Bbb{C}$; only, one of them would be the identity. Also, currently your notation is a bit ambiguous: in your example it would be better if you wrote $K := \Bbb{Q}[X]/(X^3-2)$.

Comment: True, and I did put "lost" into quotation marks precisely because of that reason. I guess what I tried to say is that it is advantageous - in my opinion - to not consider $K$ as a subfield of $\mathbb{C}$ but as an abstract field equipped with a certain number of embeddings.

Answer (score 3):

A number field has a purely abstract definition, however every one of them is isomorphic to a subfield of $\mathbb C$.  Does that answer your question?

Comment: When you say the def. of a number field, you mean as a finite extension over $ \mathbb Q $ ? or can we think $ K$ in a different way, somehow like a quotient of $ \mathbb Q $ ( When I say as a quotient I have in mind that if you take the quotient with a maximal ideal then you obtain a field, is it possible to do something similar here? )

Comment: Yes, abstractly a number field is $\mathbb Q[x]/(f(x))$.  But that is always isomorphic to a subfield of $\mathbb C$.

Comment: where $f(x)$ is an irreducible polynomial with coefficients in $ \mathbb Q $ of deg $n$ right ? Sorry, for getting into so much detalis...I just want to be sure that I understand everything  completely....

Comment: Yes $f$ is irreducible.  Any number field is of that form.

Answer (score 3):

A number field is a *finite* extension of $\Bbb{Q}$. As such, it is always isomorphic to a subfield of $\Bbb{C}$: there are exactly $[K:\Bbb{Q}]$ copies of $K$ in $\Bbb{C}$, corresponding to the different embeddings $K \to \Bbb{C}$.

While we can think of $K$ as an abstract field, e.g. as a quotient of $\Bbb{Q}[X]$ (such a thing *cannot* be contained in $\Bbb{C}$: why?), it can be useful to identify it with one of its copies in $\Bbb{C}$, for example to define an absolute value on $K$. Indeed, each pair of conjugate embeddings (or a single embedding, if its image is in $\Bbb{R}$) gives rise to a different absolute value on $K$, which extends the usual absolute value on $\Bbb{Q}$...

---

The above question was meant as a thought exercise, though maybe its formulation was a bit hasty. A quotient of $\Bbb{Q}[X]$ is a collection of subsets of $\Bbb{Q}[X]$, which are not elements of $\Bbb{C}$, at least with the usual definitions of $\Bbb{C}$.

True, we could define $\Bbb{C}$ as the completion of $K = \Bbb{Q}[X]/(X^2 + 1)$ with respect to an extension of $|\cdot|$ (in which case of course $K$ would be contained in $\Bbb{C}$), though I doubt that the OP is using this definition...